# Camera does not open when attempting to run a face recognition program (opencv-python, deepface)

Tags: python, opencv, deepface

I am following a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQvkoaevVMk), My camera isn't activating once the code is run, i tried googling answer but cant seem to figure it out. I am new to deepface and opencv-python.

here is my code

```
import threading

import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

counter = 0

reference_img = cv2.imread("img.png")  # use your own image here

face_match = False


def check_face(frame):
    global face_match
    try:
        if DeepFace.verify(frame, reference_img.copy())['verified']:
            face_match = True
        else:
            face_match = False
    except ValueError:
        face_match = False


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret:
        if counter % 30 == 0:
            try:
                threading.Thread(target=check_face, args=(frame.copy(),)).start()
            except ValueError:
                pass
        counter += 1
        if face_match:
            cv2.putText(frame, "MATCH!", (20, 450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame, "NO MATCH!", (20, 450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow('video', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

any ideas?

I made sure I installed all the correct packages (opencv-python and deepface).

Comment: what's your os? what're versions of used packages? what's python version?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Mac, deepface 0.0.79, opencv-python 4.5.5.62, python 3.9

Comment: Appearantly DSHOW is Windows only. This topic here has an answer regarding that, but the alternatives are only for Linux.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558539/cv2-videocapture0-cv2-dshow-returns-none

Answer (score 0):

DeepFace comes with out-of-the-box stream function covering real time facial recognition and facial attribute analysis. Just run the following code. As a db_path, you should reference a folder including facial photos. If you do not want to perform facial recognition, and just want to perform facial attribute analysis, you can set this to a empty folder.

```py
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/database")
```